# Property initializers are not allowed in interfaces

Tags: kotlin, interface

My Java project has an ItemType interface with the given values, which is implement by some classes. How can I implement this interface on Kotlin?

```
public interface ItemType {

int TYPE_OPTION = 2;
int TYPE_GRID = 3;
int TYPE_CAROUSEL = 4;
int TYPE_MUSIC = 5;
int TYPE_GUESS = 6;

int getItemType();

}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be better as an enum?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `companion object`:

```
interface ItemType {
    val itemType: Int

    companion object {
        const val TYPE_OPTION = 2
        const val TYPE_GRID = 3
        const val TYPE_CAROUSEL = 4
        const val TYPE_MUSIC = 5
        const val TYPE_GUESS = 6
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you put the reason why an issue occurs and how the solution works.